# Basic math functions in JavaScript to show on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make major of basic math functions (addition, subtraction, ect.) to develop in JavaScript. Input parameters should be from HTML webpage, than do the in JavaScript and return result on the same HTML page.

```js
function math() {
  //document.getElementById("frm1").innerHTML;
  var numb = document.getElementById("number").innerHTML;
  var mod = document.getElementById("modifier").innerHTML;
  console.log(numb);
  console.log(mod);
  var sum = 1; //numb + mod; //the 1 is a placeholder
  console.log(sum);
  sum = document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<form id="frm1" action="randScript.js">
  Number: <input type="int" name="number" id="number"><br> Modifiers: <input type="int" name="modifier" id="modifier"><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="math()" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id="sum"></p>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. What exact problem are you facing? See https://stackoverflow.com/help for guidance on how to improve your question. :)

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't edit your question to include the word "solved".

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve inputs values properly use `value` rather then `innerHtml`.

Retrieved values are `strings` so you need to parse them to `numbers` (with `parseInt`) before using them in math.

```
function math() {
  const numb = document.getElementById("number").value;
  const mod = document.getElementById("modifier").value;
  sum = document.getElementById("sum").innerText = parseInt(numb) + parseInt(mod);
}
```

Comment: Answers containing only code are generally not that helpful. Why was the code of OP not working? How does your code solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try that if you want to display the sum at the html element:

```
document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
```

But a more precise Question would help!

Comment: now im getting an error message saying 'sum is not defined'

Comment: @Andon1379 Is var sum = 1 used before my code sniped?

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag has an `action` attribute. This means the page will submit your information to the specified page. You can use jQuery to prevent the form from submitting.

```
$("#yourFormId").on("submit",function(event){event.preventDefault()})
```

You can also edit the forms `action` attribute itself to prevent it from submitting.

```
<form id="frm1" action"javascript:void(0);">
```

Answer (score 0):

First: The type is text - there is no "int" thing

```
 Number: <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
```

Second: if we read a bit documentation we figure also out how to get the alue into the JS part

```
  var numb = document.getElementById("number").value;
```

here you can now do your further homework ;)

Third: Get things back:
either use another input. They work two ways.

```
 document.getElementById("result").value="I did not do my homework alone"
```

or you place a div somewhere with an id

```
<div id="result"> </div>
```

and now you can really use innerHTML in js

```
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="I am too lazy";
```

The rest and to put it all together is now up to you :) Have fun to study :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `int` type for form inputs in HTML you can learn here about input types: [HTML form input types](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

```
<form id="frm1" >
        Number1: <input type="number" name="number" id="number1"><br>
        Number2: <input type="number" name="number" id="number2"><br>
        Modifiers: <input type="text" name="modifier" id="modifier"><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="math()" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id = "sum"></p>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function math() {  
  var numb1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);
  var numb2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value);
  var mod = document.getElementById("modifier").value;
  if(mod == '+'){
    var sum = numb1 + numb2;


  }else if(mod == '-'){
    var sum = numb1 - numb2;

  }else if(mod == '*'){
    var sum = numb1 * numb2;
  }
  if(sum === undefined){
    alert('invalid inputs');
    return false;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum; 
  }

  return true;


}
```